# Why does my website look different on pc and android vs ios for a reactjs page?

Tags: html, css, ios, reactjs, mobile

My responsive reactjs web page looks the same on google chrome on pc and android, but for some reason looks different (loading animation and green line generated from box-shadow) on google chrome on IOS.

[This is the link for the website](https://main--bloxcross-copytrade.netlify.app/)

How it looks on PC (responsive):

[image]

How it looks android:
[image]

How it looks on IOS:
[image]
[image]

[This is the link for the website](https://main--bloxcross-copytrade.netlify.app/)

Answer (score 0):

For the the shimmer effect, it seems theres a bug that in IOS that hasn't been fixed, it has to do with overflow:hidden and border-radios. The solution is to add "transform: translateZ(0);" in the styles. For more information see this [github post](https://gist.github.com/domske/b66047671c780a238b51c51ffde8d3a0).

Also, I solved the green line by adding an element on top with a z index higher than the element with the box shadow, as a work around.